# How to set PHP variable to a default string if the POST content is empty?

Tags: php

I have the following:

```
<?php

    $one = "hello";

    if(isset($_POST['one'])){
        $one = $_POST['one'];
    }

?>
```

The issue is I have a bunch of variables in the same format as this - is there a shorter way to default a variable to a value if the `$_POST` does not exist? Perhaps a one-liner?

Note, it does not matter if the `$_POST['var']` variable is empty or not, just if it exists

Comment: `$one = $_POST['one'] ?? 'hello';` [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: @MarkusZeller Doesn't work unfortunately, it sets the `$one` variable to `` (empty), even though `$_POST['one']` wasn't passed into the POST header

Comment: This will work. Read the linked documentation and scroll down to Null Coalescing Operator for an example.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['one'])` gives back what?

Comment: Merge `$_POST` array with array of predefined values.

Comment: if it sets the $one variable to empty string, then, logically speaking, $_POST['one'] **was** passed.